# Could we have a shortcut "magic link" to the "Good Subjective, Bad Subjective" blog post?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, hyperlinks, magic-links

Mainly, just like we map [help] and [tour], I'd love to be able to map [gsbs] to the Stack Overflow blog post "Good Subjective, Bad Subjective" (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) since we use it so often.

I'm quite aware that I can script this in Greasemonkey, but this seems to be a rather more useful pattern than for me personally.

Comment: [clicks upvote button manically]

Comment: Why can't I upvote more than once...

Comment: Testing: [gsbs]

Comment: Drat. Oh well. Wouldn't it have been humorous if it already worked?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually possible in the platform per-site, but if it is, this would be great.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'd like if it _was_ network-wide. Wouldn't break anything, and I'd use it on plenty of other sites.

Comment: @doppelgreener Just that if it needs to be network-wide, it's probably necessary to take it to Meta.SE and will likely be slow to happen if at all. But if it's per-site, implementing would be very fast if it happened.

Comment: Wait, [help] and [tour] are mapped? And here I was, copying the URL in by hand every time...

Comment: @MrLemon Also `[chat]`, `[meta]`, and `[*.se]` where * is the website prefix for any given Stack site.

Comment: +1 just for showing that you can map to these pages.

Comment: @Erik [ask] and [answer] also work `[ask]` and `[answer]`

Answer (score 2):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future.